# How to use mat-text-column in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do you set the `dataAccessor` in `mat-text-column` from the HTML? The documentation doesn't contain any examples. Note that the signature of `dataAccessor` is a function:

```
dataAccessor: (data: T, name: string) => string;
```

Comment: can you explain more what your trying say

Comment: simplified question, how do you use mat-text-column in Angular Material?  There are no examples and I cannot find the module import.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**_renderPrice**" is used as the dataAccessor function in the following example. The function receives an object of type as defined by the dataSource as parameter and must return a string. It gets called once for every row in the table.

```
@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: 'app-orderpositions',
    template: `
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="positions">
    <mat-text-column name="price" justify="end" 
                     [headerText]="'BESTELLUNG.POSITIONEN.PREIS' | translate"
                     [dataAccessor]="_renderPrice">
    </mat-text-column>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="_displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: _displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  `
})
export class OrderpositionsComponent {

  @Input()
  positions: Orderposition[];

  readonly _displayedColumns: string[] = ['price'];

  _renderPrice(position: Orderposition): string {
    return `${position.price} EUR`;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This saved my day. But I cannot use any component variable inside the render function. For instance let's say we want to set 'EUR' with a variable inside the component. It doesn't allowed me to do so. Any clue?